# Ant - Using Resource Unions with Macrodef

Tags: ant

I have an Ant Macrodef that has an `<element>` placeholder. I am attempting to use the `<element>` to pass a `resourceCollection` for processing. The contents of the `<element>` is populated correctly prior to invoking the macrodef. Unfortunately, during invocation, it comes in as empty.

Macrodef:

```
<macrodef name="doStuff" description="Amazing macrodef that fails me.">
    <element name="fs" optional="true" description="resource/element/fileset to be manipulated />
    <sequential>
        <echo message="fs: ${toString:fs}" />
        <pathconvert property="outputProp" pathsep=" ">
            <fs />
        </pathconvert>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

and it is invoked via the following pieces of a `build.xml` file I have:

```
<fileset id="files1" dir=".">
    <include name="inc/*" />
    <include name="lib/*" />
</fileset>
<fileset id="files2" dir=".">
    <include name="bin/*" />
</fileset>
<union id="allFiles">
    <resources refid="files1" />
    <resources refid="files2" />
</union>

<target name="doStuffToFiles">
     <doStuff>
         <fs>
             <resources refid="allFiles" />
         </fs>
      </doStuff>
 </target>
```

Comment: I'm unclear on which part is appearing empty. When your `echo` command is executed, are the files printed out as expected with `${toString:fs}`, and it's simply the `pathconvert` task with the nested element that isn't working? Or is the `toString` not giving you anything either?

Comment: Hey @CAustin - thanks for taking the time to think through this (and for putting up with a pretty terribly asked question - my apologies). There were a number of things that have failed me here - specifically me trying to do things that Ant doesn't support out of the box (the output of element, for example). In short, the `echo` was confusing me into thinking that the element was empty. I then assumed that the `pathconvert` task was working fine just on empty data. I'll post how I "fixed" the issue into a good enough state for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure why, but going through the union and resources, instead of using a direct fileset with a refid, seemed to be confusing my Ant setup. The following has worked for me on Ant 1.9.2

```
<macrodef name="doStuff" description="Amazing macrodef that fails me.">
    <element name="fs" 
             optional="false" 
             description="resource/element/fileset to be manipulated />
    <sequential>
        <pathconvert property="outputProp" pathsep=" ">
            <fs />
            <map from="${basedir}/" to=""/>
        </pathconvert>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>


<target name="doStuffToFiles">
    <fileset id="files1" dir=".">
        <include name="inc/**"/>
        <include name="lib/**"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset id="files2" dir=".">
        <include name="bin/**"/>
    </fileset>

    <doStuff>
        <fs>
            <fileset refid="files1" />
            <fileset refid="files2" />
        </fs>
    </doStuff>
</target>
```